# Keyword matching optimization

Tags: php, optimization, pattern-matching

In my website there is an option to search for archived articles. It works fine, but what I want to do now is to highlight the matching words in the results previews' snippets (like [Google](http://www.google.com) does).

```
$keywords = explode( $query );
```

In `$keywords` I store the keywords of the search query. And then, when preparing each result to be shown, I do the following:

```
$exploded  = explode( ' ', $text );
$count     = count( $exploded );
$text      = ''; // clears the text

for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if ( preg_grep( "/{$exploded[$i]}/i", $keywords ) ) {
        $exploded[$i] = '<strong>' . $exploded[$i] . '</strong>';
    }

    $text .= $exploded[$i] . ' ';
}
```

Where `$text` is the text for the current result's preview snippet. So basically, if a word matches (case insensitive-ly) it becomes surrounded by a [strong element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/strong).

My question is: is there a way to optimize this further? Because this script, which is `O(n^2)` (because of the [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) calls inside the for loop) is executed for each of the results, that would make the whole script `O(n^3)`. And `O(n^3)` is *a lot* in a practical situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple modification you could do (which is still fairly slow, but should be a lot faster) is to use `preg_replace` instead. Here is an example:

```
$pattern = '/(' . implode('|', explode( $query )) . ')/i';
$replacement = '<strong>${1}</strong>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
```

This would wrap all words in `$query` in strong tags in the $text.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked perfectly and it's much more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Normally, search engines would use indexes to achieve this goal.

1. Check all of your articles for keywords
2. Create a table in database, containing each keyword and the document they described in
3. For each given keyword, check the table, and provide the results for user from database

The complexity would be in two steps:

1. Database creation: O(n^2)
2. Database Lookup: O(n)

Which means slow database creation, but faster lookup.

[This](http://www.slideshare.net/phpbarcelona/text-indexing-and-search-libraries-for-php-zo-slattery-barcelona-php-conference-2008-presentation) might be useful.

Comment: This would be for a major optimization though, but interesting. I'll look further into it